# Can't shutdown and logout from top panel in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: unity, shutdown, logout

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. Shutdown and logout from the top panel are not working.

They worked fine when installing the OS, but a few days back I installed fglrx drivers for my ATI graphics card. They didn't work and I got low resolution problems and Ubuntu didn't boot. I solved it by removing the fglrx graphic driver from the recovery mode and Ubuntu started to boot and work just fine, at least that's what I thought.

But now the shutdown and logout options in the top panel don't work. I have to logout using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> and shutdown with the shutdown option in the top panel (shutdown option works after logging out but not when logged in as a user).

I re-installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and shutdown options worked fine but after installing updates they stopped working again. I thought its the graphic driver fglrx installation problem but now i know its not that. I think its a problem with some file that got installed from Ubuntu updates. 
Does any one know how to solve it?

Comment: Do you use Cairo Dock? There is [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112) related to shutdown dialog.

Comment: yes i use Cairo Dock

Comment: Cairo dock is the problem now the options are working fine thanks to you Xeranas

Comment: as stated in the bug report, this is also triggered by other docks, like Plank, in fact by any application which is registered to LauncherEntry interface of Unity DBus and is started before Unity

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Removing Cairo-dock from the startup applications solved my problem its due to a bug as commented by Xeranas

Comment: you should mark [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/451070/47206) answer as best

Answer (score 15):

No need to remove cairo-dock from start-up applications.

Use one of the these solutions:

- Find **cairo-dock.desktop** file `~/.config/autostart` and add this code,`X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20`

Steps to solve easily (tested in Ubuntu 14.04)

1. Run `gedit` without root
2. Click open file menu and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
3. Open file `~/.config/autostart/cairo-dock.desktop`
4. Add this

   ```
   X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
   ```
5. Save and close
6. Reboot your unity/gnome

Delay time more than 20 works fine.

or:

- Select cairo-dock startup application from startup application and change **command** option to:

  ```
  sh -c "sleep 30; exec cairo-dock -o"
  ```

  source [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451791/problems-with-shutdown-and-logout-after-upgrading-to-14-04)

or

- Create a script called `startdock`, with the text

  ```
  #! /bin/sh -e
  sleep 20
  cairo-dock
  exit 0
  ```

  Make it executable, and in the startup items add a new command with path to this script.

---

This is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112) as indicated in a comment. The bug report states that

*Unity's shutdown/restart dialogue is not working when another application is registered to LauncherEntry interface of Unity DBus.
It seems we have this bug when Cairo-Dock (and its Launcher-API-Deamon), DockbarX or Plank are launched before Unity.*

To solve the same problem with Plank dock, replace `cairo-dock` with `plank` in one of the above solutions. The same for other applications.

Comment: @cipricus I have posted an answer which eliminates the 20 second delay for the opening of Cairo Dock on startup which occurs by this method.

Answer (score 2):

This method is better than the others since the problem is solved and Cairo Dock starts with almost no delay.

Edit `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairo-dock/cairo-dock-launcher-API-daemon` as root.

Add the following line at line 33:

`from time import sleep`

and the following line at line 241 (just before ULWatcher()):

`sleep(5)`

Then, restart the session.

If you're using a 32bit version of Ubuntu, the file will probably be in -

`/usr/lib/cairo-dock/cairo-dock-launcher-API-daemon`

This solution has been taken from the Launchpad [Bug Page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112).

Comment: Great, but I do not know whether it's better; the 15 secs difference may or may not be more important than the fact that this is a bit more difficult to implement than the other solutions; also, it looks limited to cairo-dock as far as I can see, while the bug is not. The other solutions can easily be adjusted to fix other docks. I use Plank myself and cannot test this now. Can it be adjusted for other docks? - While the above bounty will be granted to the other answer, I do not mind granting a second :)

Comment: I use Cairo and after trying all the methods to solve the problem, I felt that this was the best solution.

Comment: as seen in the bug report linked in other answer and comment, this is caused not only by Cairo Dock. I only wanted to point out that while for the author of the question  as well as for you the problem is solved by adjusting cairo's startup, it is not solved in all cases in this way. asking a new question about plank would be a duplicate of this one, because it is the same problem, and needs (and has, in the other answer) the same solution. on the other hand, it might be possible for your solution to be transposed for Plank, but I do not know how

Comment: Ok.I didn't know that Plank has the same bug. Thanks for letting me know. I will try to modify this solution so that it works with Plank also.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't Plank the default dock on Elementary OS?

Comment: yes, but it's an independent project. like cairo, can be used in any desktop but it's lighter and simpler

Answer (score 0):

### Shutdown using power menu

You can shutdown your system alternatively. Press **Power Button** and it should display menu with options to choose from:

- Lock
- Suspend
- Reboot
- Shutdown

Choose shutdown. It will work.

[image: Power menu]
*Screenshot*

### Shutdown using terminal

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type: `sudo shutdown -h now`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Enter your password if needed
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again

You're done.

Answer (score -1):

I too have faced this problem and now the problem is solved. So, here I am going to share my experiences:
First use shortcut key Alt+Ctl+L and lock your Ubuntu and then from the top right corner click on the setting button and then click on switch user. 
Then, Click on the setting button and then click on shutdown.
Start your computer again.
Now you can easily shutdown from the top panel.

Hope you will get your problem solved.
Thanks !

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i reinstalled my OS few hours back now its working fine

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
sudo -i
gedit /etc/default/grub
```

find the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

save the file and close it.

now run

```
update-grub
```

now i think your problem solved.

Comment: I added the 'acpi=force' after quiet splash and rebooted but that didn't work, still the options(shutdown and logout) in top panel are not working

Comment: this did not worked for me !