# Problems with "Shutdown" and "LogOut" after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, menu

I have upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 on my laptop. The upgrade was successful, but the issue is that nothing happens now when I click on "LogOut", "Shutdown", "Suspend" from the top  right power icon  (not sure if this is the proper name); "Systems Settings", on the other hand works and launchs the associated window. Not a big issue, though, since I can logout and shutdown from a terminal, but I'd like to know why is this not working and how can it be fixed. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Does the machine shut down when you type `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown` on a terminal?

Comment: @Jobin No. I get the message `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files`.

Comment: hmm - this feels like a bug and maybe should be reported on Launchpad for the developers to investigate.  If you find a confirmed 14.04 bug report then flag and we can close and return the bounty to you.

Comment: Does the machine shut down when you type `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true` on a terminal?

Comment: @Jobin Yes, it does shutdown, so you're on the right track, however, I tried the suggestion by Sylvain Pineau with no success; I removed and reinstalled `indicator-session` but the problem is still there.

Comment: One thing you could attach to your question is the output of `dbus-monitor --system > $HOME/poweroff_debug`. Start the dbus monitoring then try to power off using the indicator. In your case just his CTRL-C to stop the process and copy the log content in a http://pastebin.ubuntu.com please

Comment: Do you have cairo dock installed?

Comment: @Jobin yes, I do.

Comment: Are you able to shut down using the cairo dock?

Comment: @Jobin Yes, I can shutdown using the Cairo dock.

Comment: It seems that this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112) is still valid then. As @fossfredom suggested you can flag your question if needed.

Comment: @fossfreedom According to comments, it is indeed a bug, and Sylvain Pineau has found it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112). You suggested to flag to close and return the bounty but, if there's no problem, I'd like to accept Jobin's answer below and award him the bounty.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - given that the bugreport was from 13.10, carried forward to 14.04 and that this is not a core ubuntu package so that it will only be finally resolved by a community update, this probably doesnt fit into the standard bug-report category.  Feel free to award the bounty if you feel the answer given has helped you.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't shutdown and logout from top panel in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451070/cant-shutdown-and-logout-from-top-panel-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Sylvain Pineau](https://askubuntu.com/users/32239/sylvain-pineau) pointed out, it seems that you [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112) affects you.

The best way you can enable shutdown/logout/suspend in the cogwheel menu is [disabling starting cairo dock at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187391/how-to-remove-cairo-dock-from-start-up) and then manually starting it(you can type "cairo dock on the dash and then click it to start cairo dock).

Another workaround for the moment until the bug gets fixed is using a keyboard shortcut to shutdown. For that open **System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts** and set a "Custom Shortcut" as follows:

1. Click on +
2. Type "Shut down" ahead of "Name"
3. Type

   ```
   dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true
   ```

   ahead of "Command" and click "Apply"
4. Click on "disable" in front of the shortcut created and press the keystrokes you want to be set for shutting down, if they are already used, you'll be warned, if not you can use that keystore for shutting down without having to enter the password as you now do using `sudo pm-poweroff`.

For a list of other commands for rebooting, suspending and hibernating refer to this question:

- [What command is executed when shutdown from the graphical menu in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454039/what-command-is-executed-when-shutdown-from-the-graphical-menu-in-14-04/454077?noredirect=1#454077)

You can similarly create shortcuts for other commands.

Comment: You have my vote for having found the relation with cairo dock, congrats.

Comment: @SylvainPineau: Thanks for pointing out it was indeed a bug, had been scratching my head for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

No need to remove cairo-dock from start-up applications, find **cairo-dock.desktop** file `~/.config/autostart` and add this code,`X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20`

Steps to solve easily (tested in Ubuntu 14.04)

1. run `gedit` without root
2. click open file menu and press Ctrl+H
3. open file `~/.config/autostart/cairo-dock.desktop`
4. add this

`X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20`

1. save and close
2. reboot your unity/gnome

Delay time more than 20 works fine.

soure [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112)

Answer (score 1):

In 14.04, such actions should use `/org/freedesktop/login1` provided by `systemd-logind`. try to reinstall the `indicator-session` package.

Open a Terminal an type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge indicator-session
sudo apt-get install indicator-session systemd-services
```

`indicator-session` roles are described here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemMenu

Comment: [Jobin's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451791/problems-with-shutdown-and-logout-after-upgrading-to-14-04/454277?noredirect=1#comment597002_451791) suggests that this might be the problem. I tried his suggestion and the computer does shutdown. I tried reinstalling `indicator-session` as you suggested, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I reinstalled indicator-session and now it won't show up unless I manually launch it.

Comment: @RolandiXor: OP problem was related to cairo-dock. Now if the indicator has to be started manually, just add it to the Startup Applications Preferences. On my system the command is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service`

Comment: I just realized the issue was related to a bug where it's not shown in Pantheon. I don't use Cairo-Dock btw.

Comment: @RolandiXor: It's an old question, but you could leave the bug number here for reference.

Comment: I'd have to dig it up lol

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Removing cairo dock from Startup Applications, you can also change *when* it starts up... I have found that 60 seconds (on my laptop at least) is sufficient time to allow for the system to start properly prior to starting cairo dock.  the following in the Command field will allow for delayed startup.

```
sh -c "sleep 60; exec cairo-dock -o"
```

You can play with the sleep time to minimize it based on the speed of your system :)

This allows the system to startup and the shutdown etc options still exist

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem on different machines after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.
To fix I had to issue 
`sudo pam-auth-update --force`

Relevant bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/1240336