# ubuntu 14.04 - everything fine except the shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 on my old notebook (Acer Travelmate 2420).

Everything is fine except the shutdown.

It's hanging in the last screen ("ubuntu" with the points beneath - they change their colour properly. As long as I don't press the "on/off" button of the notebook).

I've changed this line:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

into this:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

it doesn't work.

Can anybody help?

I'm a ubuntu beginner, so I maybe don't understand too specific things.

Comment: did you run `update-grub` after you change that line?

Comment: so you did it before I told you that? what is `kernel` version in your system `uname -r` ?

Comment: yes, i've done the things step by step as written down somewhere in the net. here is what comes, if i type "uname -r":  3.13.0-29-generic

Comment: take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/451791/problems-with-shutdown-and-logout-after-upgrading-to-14-04 there's a lot of issues can be that you can find within forum

Answer (score 0):

While you see that purple screen, you can press ESC to see exactly what Ubuntu is doing, which may be very useful if this turns out to be a bug, or if you just want to see what is taking so long.

Try going into Terminal and typing `sudo shutdown -P now` that ought to force Ubuntu to completely shutdown, if not then we may have to dig deeper.

Comment: the last 2 lines are:  * Unmounting local filesystems  [OK]       * Will now halt

Comment: it's still the same with: sudo shutdown -P now

Comment: Sounds like an uncommon but not unheard of bug. I refer you here: http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.com/2011/11/solved-ubuntu-doesnt-shutdown-properly.html?m=1        In the hopes your grub is configured similarly. With any luck you may have just been missing two lines of grub args.

Comment: after several grub-changes i decided to install a new operating system. tried lubuntu: same problem. tried ubuntu studio: everything works as far as i can see including the shutdown. so all seems to be good in the end.